# Fill an empty matrix with data of different lengths

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, variable-length

Hi i have written a code that supposed to get finance data from Fred. 
Its supposed to get all the data and them put the data into an empty matrix.

This seem a litle bit harder than i thought. For example:

```
tickers = c("AAA", "BAA", "TB3MS")

###HÄMTAR DATA###
library(quantmod)
var = noquote(tickers)
getSymbols(tickers, src = "FRED")

#kontrollera längderna och skapa en vector med längderna
vector = c()
for (v in 1:length(var)) {
    vector[v] = length(get(var[v]))
}
minsta = min(vector)
längsta = max(vector)

emptym = matrix( nrow = längsta, ncol = length(tickers)+1)

for (i in 1:length(var)) {
    emptym[,i] = get(var[i])
}
```

but since TB3MS is shorter than the two other sets, i get an error.

```
"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"
```

Im trying to figur out how to get around this?
Make a for loop inside the for loop?

I have also tried this one:

```
cbind.fill <- function(...){
    nm = list(...) 
    nm = lapply(nm, as.matrix)
    n = max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
    do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
        rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}
```

But this one gives the NA at the ending i need the NA from the beginning and then fill it with data.

Comment: What is the values of `get(var[i])`?

Comment: its the rows with data, for example the first i=1 get(var[1]) = all the data for AAA.